# Correct resetting the counter in nested ordered lists in css

Tags: html, css

I want to number a nested ordered list over the ::marker pseudo element.
In an ordinary ordered list this is just right. However, if the ordered list is nested in an unordered list, then the unordered list affects the order and nesting of the ordered list.
How do I get the list resetted correctly?

```css
ol li {
  padding-left: 0.5em
}

ol li::marker {
  content: counters(list-item, ".") "";
}
```

```html
<h2>Correct nested ol oumbers</h2>
<ol>
  <li>One
    <ol>
      <li>One One</li>
      <li>One Two</li>
      <li>One three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ol>

<h2>Not correct nested ol numbers</h2>
<ul>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item
    <ol>
      <li>One
        <ol>
          <li>One One</li>
          <li>One Two</li>
          <li>One three</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Looking for this `ul { list-style-type: decimal; }`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out myself, ich have to set an own counter and increment it and reset it.

```css
 
ol {
counter-set: ol-item 0;
}

ol ol {
  counter-set: ol-item 0;
  counter-reset: ol-item 1;
}
       
ol li {  
 padding-left: 0.5em;
 counter-increment: ol-item;
}
 
ol li::marker {
 content: counters(ol-item, ".") "";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>One
    <ol>
      <li>One One</li>
      <li>One Two</li>
      <li>One three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ol>


<ul>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item
    <ol>
      <li>One
        <ol>
          <li>One One</li>
          <li>One Two</li>
          <li>One three</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>
```